# Silverlight RIA Application that only accepts registered users

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

I have implemented the RIA WCF side to authenticate with Forms Authentication and everything works from the client as expected.

This application should only allow registered users to use it (users are created by admin - no registeration page).

My question is then, what (or where) should be the efficient way to make the authentication; it has to show up at application start up (unless remember me was on and cookie is still active) and if the user logs out, it should automatically get out the interface and return to login form again.

**Update** (code trimmed for brevity):

```
Public Class MainViewModel
   ....

   Public Property Content As Object 'DP property

   Private Sub ValidateUser()
       If Not IsUserValid Login()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Login()
     'I want, that when the login returns a success it should continue
     'navigating to the original content i.e.
     Dim _content = Me.Content
     Me.Content = Navigate(Of LoginPage) 
     If IsUserValid Then Me.Content = _content
   End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw you other question so I assume you're using mvvm.  I accomplish this by creating a RootPage with a grid control and a navigation frame.  I set the RootVisual to the RootPage.  I bind the navigation frames source to a variable in the RootPageVM, then in the consructor of RootPageVM you can set the frame source to either MainPage or LoginPage based on user auth.  RootPageVM can also receive messages to control further navigation like logging out.

Using MVVM-Light.

So, in the RootPageView (set as the RootVisual), something like:

```
public RootPageViewModel()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>
      (this, "NavigationRequest", Navigate);

    if (IsInDesignMode)
    {
    }
    else
    {               
        FrameSource = 
          WebContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated ?
          "Home" : 
          "Login";               
    }
}
```

And a method for navigation:

```
private void Navigate(NotificationMessage obj)
{          
    FrameSource = obj.Notification;
}
```

In the LoginViewModel:

```
if (loginOperation.LoginSuccess)
{                                                           
    Messenger.Default.Send
      (new NotificationMessage(this, "Home"), "NavigationRequest");        
}
```

Comment: IDK, how where and how I should create the handlers for the `AuthenticationService`'s events, and how to manage it in the UI; I need to kick out the user immediately when he becomes unauthenticated. the program is only meant to serve registered users, unauth. users should see an error/deadend screen.

Comment: I have logic in the LoginViewModel, if the user authenticates I send a message that will be received in the RootPageViewModel telling it to navigate to the MainPage.  You can do the same when they log out, send a message to navigate back to the LoginPage.

Comment: I prefer using the EventAggregator of PRISM, but IDK how.

Comment: In the NavDemo source, https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo, a RootView and LoginView could be added just as MainView and the SubViews in the NavDemo.  Then set RootView as the RootVisual.

Comment: How is the events and the view management maintained by Prism? I prefer sticking to prism rather than MvvmLight.

Comment: I don't know, the concepts should be similar, I haven't dove into Prism yet but I plan on it.

Comment: @Derek, thanks for all your responses. I've decided that I won't be using URI for navigation. instead I created in the main container a `ContentControl` that its `Content` property is bound to a corresponding `Content` property in the vm. I want to navigate to the `LoginView` (setting the current content to it) but I also want to get a result from the `LoginView` on a successful login, so I can redirect user to original content, how do I do this?

Comment: @Derek, I've added some content to my question explaining what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do that authentication in the LoginViewModel, it handles the Login button click, makes the asynchronous call to RIA, on the callback, if valid send a navigation message to the Root to switch content.